# Reading text file containing numerical values in R

Tags: r, input, dataframe

I know there are posts on this topic but nothing I have read and tried so far seems to work. This should be simple but it apparently is not. I have a parameter file that contains both characters and text. When I read it with:

```
parmData <- read.table("ParameterData.txt”)
```

and I print the values to the screen I get the following frame. Each object in the frame is apparently a factor.

```
     V1
1    10
2     5
3     8
4   0.3
5   0.5
6   VAL
```

I first tried loading these into separately labelled variables such as:

```
var1 <- as.numeric(parmData[1,1])  ## with as.character used for the VAL value
```

All goes well until I get to the real numbers like 0.3, 0.5, etc. The conversion to numeric converts these values to integers ... 3 and 5. I’ve tried everything ... e.g., using the `parmData` values without reassignment, but these are in fact `factors`, and factors don’t work in some of the methods I am using.

Surely this is easy and I am blind to something. I want numeric values treated as numerical and character values treated as characters. How do I do this?

Here is what the data file looks like:

```
10   ## lookback days
5    ## lookback days
8    ## Volatility lookback days
0.3  ## weighting 1
0.5  ## weighting 2
0.2  ## Volatility weighting
8    ## averaging period 1
10   ## averaging period 2
12   ## averaging period 3
"SHY"   ## cutoff asset
0.03 ## no-risk percentage (decimal)
0.3  ## maximum amount allowed (decimal)
5    ## lookback days for correlation 
5    ## lookback days covariance
```

Comment: `parmData <- read.table("ParameterData.txt”, na.strings = 'VAL')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have character and numeric in the same column. You also cannot convert factors directly to numeric and get the correct value. Factors are stored as integer values that will probably be different from the values you have.  We have to first convert to character, then to numeric.

`VAL` will have to be `NA`, or the whole column will have to be character. For numeric:

```
suppressWarnings(with(df, as.numeric(levels(V1)[V1])))
#[1] 10.0  5.0  8.0  0.3  0.5   NA
```

And for character just remove the `as.numeric` call from above.  You can also remove the `suppressWarnings` call if you want.  It's only warning us about the `NA` values being introduced.

---

**Update :**  Based on your edit, I would use `scan` with many of its arguments.

```
scan(text = txt, what = character(), quote = "\"", sep = "\n",   
     comment.char = "#", strip.white = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)
#  [1] "10"   "5"    "8"    "0.3"  "0.5"  "0.2"  "8"    "10"   "12"   "SHY" 
# [11] "0.03" "0.3"  "5"    "5"
```

Where `text = txt` would be replaced with your file name.  And then use `as.numeric` on that vector if you want to convert to numerics.

```
txt <- '10   ## lookback days
5    ## lookback days
8    ## Volatility lookback days
0.3  ## weighting 1
0.5  ## weighting 2
0.2  ## Volatility weighting
8    ## averaging period 1
10   ## averaging period 2
12   ## averaging period 3
"SHY"   ## cutoff asset
0.03 ## no-risk percentage (decimal)
0.3  ## maximum amount allowed (decimal)
5    ## lookback days for correlation 
5    ## lookback days covariance '
```

Comment: I do need to somehow input this character parameter. So, are you saying I should have a separate data file for this one character parameter?

Comment: No, I'm saying that if all the non-values are `VAL`, then you can re-read the file with the `read.table` call above and it will convert them all to NA

Comment: OK. I think I am muddying the water. I edited my post to show exactly what the input file looks like on the disk. I can’t use the comments unless I use the read.table, I believe. But, they are not necessary.

Comment: @Ernie - I've added a possible method to my answer based on your input file

Comment: OK. Thanks for explaining the data format of the frame. I thought the power of the frame was the ability to have different variable types, but apparently that does not apply the same way when reading data in.

I just removed the character variable from the list. It worked fine then. I will construct a character-only file for inputting non-numeric parameters.

Comment: It can have different types in the columns.  That's the advantage of a data frame over a matrix.  But within each column, all values must be the same type.  Also, I've added an even better `scan` method to the answer.